# Is there any way to get the server's id without a message from the server?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a python music bot with the option of a queue of songs for every server and it worked but the only problem was that the queue was one for all the servers (the "queue" was actually a list).

so I thought "ok i'll just create a dict where the keys are the servers's id's and the values are the queues" but it's problematic to do it because if I change the queue on the on_message function it changes it on every message to every server that wants to get info about the queue which makes this entire thing worthless.

here are the stuff I referred to - I wont add more to clutter the question because it doesn't really matter

```
queues = {}
queue = []
async def on_message(ctx):
    server = ctx.server
    id = server.id
    queues[id] = queue  # this is where I want to create an empty queue for every server so it shouldn't be here
```

is there any way to do this queue thing in my method without using actual queues from async? because I expect this to be possible and it works in the case of one server, there must be a way to generalize this

Answer (score 0):

In your `on_ready` event, you can initialize a mapping of server ids to empty lists:

```
queues = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for server in bot.servers:
        queues[server.id] = []
```

Comment: @idanb Please mark this solution as the official answer if it helped you.